# How to send Image and text from android application to sql server using web api

Tags: android, asp.net-web-api

I am able to send individually Image and text but I want to send image and text together
Please help me anyone

Comment: Please Search before posting question here

Answer (score 0):

Use multipart. Using multipart you can send images video and other files with your text data. Various library is available to send data in multipart. Ion is one of them

Answer (score 0):

one way is You can convert image to Base64 string in web api

```
public static String imageToString(Bitmap BitmapData) {

        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        BitmapData.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);
        byte[] byte_arr = bos.toByteArray();

        String file = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, Base64.DEFAULT);
        //appendLog(file);
        return file;
}
```

you can convert bitmap image to Base64 string in above function and pass string parameter in your api and decode those string in server side

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all of you specially thanks to Bhupat Bheda. I Complete my full project. Now I want to share my research.

```
private void saveText() {

    String image= getStringImage(rotatedBMP);
    ImageCapture imageCapture = new ImageCapture();

    imageCapture.Name = prescriptionName.getText().toString();
    imageCapture.Remarks = remarks.getText().toString();
    imageCapture.ImageURL=mCurrentPhotoPath;
    imageCapture.PhotoName=photoName;
    imageCapture.Image=image;

    imageCapture.Id = _ImageId_Id;
    if (_ImageId_Id == 0) {
        restService.getService().InsertPrescription(imageCapture, new Callback<ImageCapture>() {
            @Override
            public void success(ImageCapture imageCapture, Response response) {
                Toast.makeText(Prescription.this, "New Record Inserted.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Home.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                Toast.makeText(Prescription.this, error.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
    }

}

private void takePhoto() {
    dispatchTakePictureIntent();
}





@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i(TAG, "onActivityResult: " + this);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        setPic();
    }
}

String mCurrentPhotoPath;
String photoName;

static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;
File photoFile = null;

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File

        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }
}



public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedImage;
}
```

For Details [How to send Image and text from android application to sql server using web api][1]

https://esoftpanel.blogspot.com/2017/04/how-to-send-image-and-text-from-android.html